# How to start Google cloud storage and let users upload without login Google account?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm totally new to Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

**Here is my scenario.**

I create a GCS for my app users to upload their media files. All the users can upload to GCS **without** login Google account **but** required an authenticated user from my app. And the upload via client browser to GCS (no server code).

After reading the documents, the `authentication` part confusing me.

1. OAuth 2.0 Authentication (Required Google account)
2. Cookie-based Authentication (Required Google account)
3. Using Service Accounts for Authentication

Can someone explain number 2 and 3 to me?
especially number 3 because it then bring me to

```
Signed url, browser upload using post, oauth2.0 for server to server application.
```

Which cause me no idea how to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) for your use case.

Depending on your use case, you can generate and display a link to a signed URL on your dynamic website, or you can provide a download link that goes through your app, sending a 302 redirect to the signed URL after authenticating the user.

Comment: so use "service account" when creating client_ID ?

Comment: Yes, install a service account on your web server that generates the signed urls